# Use of complex projective plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, projective-geometry

What are complex projective planes good for?
that is, are there any examples of important (or just) theorems one can prove using complex projective planes?

Thanks.

Comment: By "complex projective plane", do you mean the complex plane $\Bbb C$ with an extension at infinity, or the "plane over $\Bbb C$", $\Bbb C^2$ with an extension at infinity?

Comment: You know that a complex [projective elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) is a compact Riemann surface isomorphic to a complex torus ?

Comment: Every n dimensional complex projective plane will do actually. I am interested in the role of   ℂ.

Comment: @Yuval what do you mean "n dimensional plane"? The plane has $2$ dimensions. You just mean $n$ dimensional projective space in general?

Comment: Take a look at any textbook on algebraic geometry. For example the book "Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry" by Miles Reid, or the book "Basic Algebraic Geometry" by Igor Shafarevich; there are numerous others. Any of those books will give many, many examples of theorems that require (1) the _projective_ plane, and (2) the _complex_ numbers (or an algebraically closed field). As a slightly trivial example, over the real numbers, the "curve" $x^2+y^2+1=0$ (or, in homogeneous coordinates, $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$) has no points; the complex numbers avoid many pathologies like this.

Comment: rschwieb, the word "plane" is used to describe the general idea of spaces satisfying certain axioms. In general, I am talking about spaces like CPn.

Comment: @ZachTeitler - In planar rigid body dynamics using homogeneous coordinates you encounter $\frac{I_c}{m} +  (x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=0$ as a curve defining the inertial properties of a body. The only points that satisfy the above are in the complex plane. So these things are not _pathologies_, but the norm, I think.

Comment: @Yuval In English, "plane" exclusively refers to the $2$-dimensional case, afaik. I think the term you want is *projective space* [see the end of the lead paragraph here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane) for example.

Comment: rschwieb, I am working with the book perspectives on projective geometry by Jurgen Richter-Gebert, and he names the axiomatic thing I mentioned before: "Projective Plane". I am very much aware of the English meaning of the word "plane".